# add newline after specific lines with sed

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed

I have output as:

```
A: this thing
B: that thing
A: 23
B: 46
A: negative
B: positive
```

which I am creating using sed/awk. How can I use sed (I'm thinking sed is the right choice?) to add a newline after every `B:` line to yield:

```
A: this thing
B: that thing

A: 23
B: 46

A: negative
B: positive
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/^B:/a\
    ' file
```

The `a` command appends what follows after the matching line.

You could also do something like `'s/^B:.*/&\n/'`, editing the line and adding a newline.

It is also easy to handle in `awk`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I like the `'s/^B:.*/&\n/'` method the best, but can you explain it a bit to me? I get that `^B:` matches lines beginning with `B:` and assume that `.*` is a wildcard, but what is the `&` doing? Does it just say "anything we asked about in the first part"?

Comment: Yes.  The `.*` matches the rest of the line (which is therefore part of the matched pattern in `&`) so that the newline goes at the end of the line rather than in the middle.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '{print} /^B:/{print ""}' file
A: this thing
B: that thing

A: 23
B: 46

A: negative
B: positive
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GNU sed` (Append hold space (blank by default) to pattern space using `G` option):

```
sed '/^B:/G' file
A: this thing
B: that thing

A: 23
B: 46

A: negative
B: positive
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `sed` ...

```
sed 's/^\(B:.*\)/\1\n/'
```

Or as [@JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) commented below:

```
sed 's/^B:.*/&\n/'
```

Comment: Or, simpler, `s/^B: .*/&\n/` with no explicit capture needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
sed -E -i 's:(^B.*$):\1\n:g' filename
```

It append a new line to every line that starts with the letter B in `filename`.

Comment: Or, simpler, `s/^B: .*/&\n/` with no explicit capture needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another `awk`

```
awk '/^B:/ {$0=$0"\n"} 1' file
A: this thing
B: that thing

A: 23
B: 46

A: negative
B: positive
```